# How can I spell check for multiple languages in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ispell

I write mostly my documentation in HTML using *emacs* as my main editor.  Emacs let you interactively spell-check the current buffer with the command `ispell-buffer`.

Since I switch between a number of languages, I have an HTML comment at the end of the file specifying the main dictionary and personal dictionary for that file,  E.g. for Norwegian (norsk) I use the following pair of dictionaries:

```
<!-- Local IspellDict: norsk -->
<!-- Local IspellPersDict: ~/.aspell/personal.dict -->
```

This works great.

However, sometimes I have a paragraph in another language (e.g. English) embedded in an otherwise Norwegian document.  Example:

```
<p xml:lang="en">This paragraph is in English.</p>
```

The spell-checker naturally flag *all* the words in such a paragraph as misspellings (since the dictionary only contain Norwegian words).

To avoid this, I've tried to add a "british" dictionary to the document, like this:

```
<!-- Local IspellDict: british -->
<!-- Local IspellDict: norsk -->
<!-- Local IspellPersDict: ~/.aspell/personal.dict -->
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The "british" dictionary is simply ignored.

My prefered solution would to load an additional dictionary and use this, toghether with the primary dictionary, for spell-checking.  Is this possible?

However, I am also interested in a solution that let me mark paragraphs for *not* being spell checked.  It is not ideal, but it would stop valid English words from being flagged as misspellings.

PS: I have also looked at the answer to this question: [Multilingual spell checking with language detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873601/multilingual-spell-checking-with-language-detection), but it is much broader and does not address the specific use *emacs ispell* for doing the spell-check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define two ispell dictionaries in Emacs for LaTeX mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361603/how-to-define-two-ispell-dictionaries-in-emacs-for-latex-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Try ispell-multi and flyspell-xml-lang http://www.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/

You can spawn multiple instances of ispell, and use the xml:lang tag to decide which language to check for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've loaded `ispell-multi` and `flyspell-xml-lang` and tagged the English paragraphs with `xml:lang="en"`, but it still ignores the "british" dictonary.  There seem to be some piece missing.